# Tracking User's Location at a certain point

Tags: rules, location

I've installed the [Time Tracker module](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_tracker).

I need to track user's location when the user clicks on "Start Timer" AND when the user clicks "Stop Timer". Please help or point me in the right direction. I tried to use rules but I didn't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You can append a different query string to each click, which will allow you to track each one individually. Lets say your "Start Timer" is at mysite.com/start_timer (using ajax). You can create several url's with a query string that lead to the buttons. Ex:

mysite.com/start_timer (using Ajax)

mysite.com/end_timer (using Ajax)

Then you can use [Google Analitics Event Tracking Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_et) which will do your work for tracking easily.

Enjoy !

Comment: I need to track the locations and put them in fields in my drupal site though. Would it still work?

Comment: You have two buttons on which a user will click, sent something unique or sent user ID when clicked on buttons using Ajax on backend. Then this module will help you a lot.

Comment: It seems that I need to have some knowledge of coding to do that, correct? I do not know how to send information but I can tell you what I see when I use firebug with these buttons. On the first button: <input type="submit" id="edit-submit--2" name="op" value="Start timer" class="form-timer_control_start"/>   ON the other button: <input type="submit" id="edit-stop" name="op" value="Stop Timer" class="form-timer_control_stop"/>